# Different dividers between items and sub items in NavigationView

Tags: android, xaml, navigationview

I trying to have dividers between items in my `NavigationView`, I tried with `DividerItemDecoration` but it didn't work exactly as I wanted.

MainActivity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:customTypeface="@string/font_lato_light"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_text_color_selector"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextViewBody"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/mainBlue"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/menu_item_bg"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is my menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:title="@string/historico" >
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_historico"
                android:icon="@drawable/user"
                android:title="@string/historico" />
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="@string/pagamento">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_pagamento"
                android:icon="@drawable/user"
                android:title="@string/pagamento" />
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="@string/definicoes">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_terms"
                android:icon="@drawable/user"
                android:title="@string/terms" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_lang"
                android:icon="@drawable/user"
                android:title="@string/alterar_idioma" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_pass"
                android:icon="@drawable/user"
                android:title="@string/gestao_pass" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_ped"
                android:icon="@drawable/user"
                android:title="@string/gestao_ped" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_info"
                android:icon="@drawable/user"
                android:title="@string/informacao_pessoal" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_faqs"
                android:icon="@drawable/user"
                android:title="@string/faqs" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_suggest"
                android:icon="@drawable/user"
                android:title="@string/Sugestoes" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_end_session"
                android:icon="@drawable/user"
                android:title="@string/terminar_sessao" />
        </menu>
    </item>
```

This is the result.
[image]

and what im trying to get is this 
[image]

Is there anyway to add diferent dividers between items and sub-items?